# Solr DIH: dataConfig is missing

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm getting this message when I'm trying to perform my import handler:

> Data Config problem: the root node `<dataConfig>` is missing

Here my data import handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">/var/solr/data/arxius/conf/arxius-data-config-dih.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

And here the data config:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.122.1;databaseName=giac_txt" user="sa" password="StR0nGp4ss."/>
    <document>
        <entity name="item" query="select codi_unitat, titol from anc_unicat">
            <field column="codi_unitat" name="code_l_ns"/>
            <field column="titol" name="title_txt_ca" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: where is the data-config file located? it would be good if you place it under the conf folder.

Comment: It's located at `/var/solr/data/arxius/conf/`

Comment: your entity is not using the datasource defined...mention a name to the datasource

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite figure out what you mean...

Comment: Recreate the data config file by referring the config file provided by solr. The XML parser is not able to identify the tags here

Comment: :) Sorry @AbhijitBashetti . I keed without understanding what would I need to do to solve that... Do you suggest me I simply change the file name from `/var/solr/data/arxius/conf/arxius-data-config-dih.xml` to `/var/solr/data/arxius/conf/configData.xml`?

Comment: no no...The structure inside the file data-config has some flaw..I am requesting you to create the new data-config file by referring solr provided data-config file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223624/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-jordi).